# Unidentified Spider

Tags: species-identification, zoology, species, arthropod, habitat

Apologies for the rubbish quality of the image, but I found this spider while in the shower. I’m not exactly sure what species it is and wonder if someone can help me out.

I live in southeast Michigan, it was a relatively humid day and it is 1 degree Centigrade presently. It is 9:29 PM EST. I’d say the body of the spider is about a centimeter long. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is Cheiracanthium sp. with common name "Yellow Sac Spider." It is very common in North American homes, distinctly identifiable by having a homogenous colour that is almost an translucent yellow (sometimes yellow-green or yellow-brown) with no particular markings (no stripes or dots) aside from the cardiac mark (the dorsal line on its abdomen).

It often has black feet like in this photo and is sometimes alternately called a 'black footed sac spider.'

There are two species of this genus widespread across North America: *C.mildei* and *C.inclusum* which are difficult to separate from photos like this. It is generally understood that *C.mildei* is commonly found indoors while *C.inclusum* is commonly found outdoors.